# extract value in XSLT from different levels and separating them with ";"

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<bp>
<bp_id>319</bp_id>
<bp_name>HPP</bp_name>
    <contact>
        <id>239764182</id>
        <first_name>abc</first_name>
        <last_name>def</last_name>
        <email>
            <id>1234</id>
            <email_address>xvxn@hddd.com</email_address>
            <is_primary>true</is_primary>
        </email>
        <phone>
            <id>222</id>
            <phone_number>773890814350</phone_number>
            <country_code>1</country_code>
            <display_name>17733338908150</display_name>
            <is_primary>true</is_primary>
            <type_id>1201</type_id>
            <type_code>Office</type_code>
        </phone>
        <bp_contact>
            <is_admin_user>false</is_admin_user>
            <is_company_officer>false</is_company_officer>
            <shared_contact_type_id>3100</shared_contact_type_id>
            <shared_contact_type_description>Direct Contact</shared_contact_type_description>
            <role>
                <role_id>8</role_id>
                <role_name>something</role_name>
                <responsibility>
                    <responsibility_id>3</responsibility_id>
                    <responsibility_name>this &amp; thats</responsibility_name>
                    <is_primary_contact>false</is_primary_contact>
                </responsibility>
                <assignment>
                    <id>1507420</id>
                    <assignment_type_id>2002</assignment_type_id>
                    <abc_ven_number>4225506</abc_ven_number>
                    <department_id>97</department_id>
                    <is_primary_contact>false</is_primary_contact>
                </assignment>
                <assignment>
                    <id>552593</id>
                    <assignment_type_id>2002</assignment_type_id>
                    <abc_ven_number>1048993</abc_ven_number>
                    <department_id>97</department_id>
                    <is_primary_contact>false</is_primary_contact>
                </assignment>
                <assignment>
                    <id>1507391</id>
                    <assignment_type_id>2002</assignment_type_id>
                    <abc_ven_number>4225506</abc_ven_number>
                    <department_id>2</department_id>
                    <is_primary_contact>false</is_primary_contact>
                </assignment>
                <assignment>
                    <id>552551</id>
                    <assignment_type_id>2002</assignment_type_id>
                    <abc_ven_number>1048993</abc_ven_number>
                    <department_id>2</department_id>
                    <is_primary_contact>false</is_primary_contact>
                </assignment>
            </role>
            <address>
                <is_address_owner>true</is_address_owner>
                <id>101227</id>
                <line1>4501 W 47th</line1>
                <city>Chicago</city>
                <postal_code>60632</postal_code>
                <country_code>US</country_code>
                <country_name>UNITED STATES</country_name>
                <subdivision_code>US-IL     </subdivision_code>
                <subdivision_name>Illinois</subdivision_name>
                <validation_status>0</validation_status>
            </address>
        </bp_contact>
    </contact>
    <merch_planning_partnership_tier_id>9801</merch_planning_partnership_tier_id>
    <merch_planning_partnership_tier_name>Basic Partner</merch_planning_partnership_tier_name>
</bp>
```

for the multiple values of abc_ven_number under assignment, I want all the values of abc_ven_number from all levels and they should be separated by semicolons.

```
4225506;1048993;4225506;1048993 -- like this.
```

Following is my XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"         xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"     xmlns:ns="http://target.com/2012/03/01/canonical/BusinessPartner"> 
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
 <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">bp_name,bp_id 
<xsl:for-each select="ns:bp_list/ns:bp">
<xsl:variable name="bp_name" select="normalize-space(ns:bp_name)" />
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(ns:contact/ns:bp_contact/ns:role/ns:assignment/ns:gms_vendor_number)"/>
<xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>  
</xsl:for-each></xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way, I am getting just the first value. I tried using "." but I only want the abc_ven_number and not the other values in that level.

Today is my first day of working on XSLT.

Comment: In your example, all the `abc_ven_number` elements are at the same level. If that's true in general, it would be more efficient to extract them using an exact, full path.

Answer (score 1):

This selects all `abc_ven_number` elements anywhere and concatenates their text with `;` as separator:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//abc_ven_number">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
      <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2, You can use xsl:value-of select with a separator

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::abc_ven_number" separator=";"/>
</xsl:template>
```

or if you want disctinct values:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(descendant::abc_ven_number)" separator=";"/>
 </xsl:template>
```